# System boot up issue

Tags: 12.04, boot

My ubuntu 12.04 freezes at login screen when starts for the first time. But after hard power off there is no problem. This bug occurs only on first boot up. This is a newly installed system. So each and every day i have to do hard power off after first boot up.